# Filter repeated data using two other column conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter the data only the group id have the same unsuppressed consecutively in type 1 just before switching to type 2.
my data is look like,

```r
data<- data.frame(
id= c(215, 215, 215, 215, 297, 297, 297,297, 297,297,317,317,317,382,382,382,459,459,459),
type=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2),
status=c("Unsuppressed","Unsuppressed","Unsuppressed","Unsuppressed","Unsuppressed","Suppressed","Unsuppressed","Unsuppressed","Suppressed",     "Suppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Unsuppressed", "Suppressed") )
```

```
data
    id type       status
1  215    1 Unsuppressed
2  215    1 Unsuppressed
3  215    2 Unsuppressed
4  215    2 Unsuppressed
5  297    1 Unsuppressed
6  297    1   Suppressed
7  297    1 Unsuppressed
8  297    2 Unsuppressed
9  297    2   Suppressed
10 297    2   Suppressed
11 317    1 Unsuppressed
12 317    1 Unsuppressed
13 317    2 Unsuppressed
14 382    1 Unsuppressed
15 382    1 Unsuppressed
16 382    2 Unsuppressed
17 459    1 Unsuppressed
18 459    2 Unsuppressed
19 459    2   Suppressed
```

I am trying

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
data1 <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Seq = map(type, ~seq.int(.x, .x + 1L))) %>%
  mutate(Flag = map_lgl(Seq, ~all(.x %in% type))) %>%
  filter(Flag) %>%
  select(-Seq, -Flag)
  %>% ungroup()
```

```
data1  
 1   215     1 Unsuppressed
 2   215     1 Unsuppressed
 3   297     1 Unsuppressed
 4   297     1 Suppressed
 5   297     1 Unsuppressed
 6   317     1 Unsuppressed
 7   317     1 Unsuppressed
 8   382     1 Unsuppressed
 9   382     1 Unsuppressed
10   459     1 Unsuppressed
```

But the desired output is

```
id      type     status
215     1       Unsuppressed
215     1       Unsuppressed
215     2       Unsuppressed
317     1       Unsuppressed
317     1       Unsuppressed
317     2       Unsuppressed
382     1       Unsuppressed
382     1       Unsuppressed
382     2       Unsuppressed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69031730/edit) your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` + `filter` -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(status == 'Unsuppressed') & sum(type == 1) > 1 & 
         (type == 1 | row_number() == match(2, type))) %>%
  ungroup

#    id  type status      
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
#1   215     1 Unsuppressed
#2   215     1 Unsuppressed
#3   215     2 Unsuppressed
#4   317     1 Unsuppressed
#5   317     1 Unsuppressed
#6   317     2 Unsuppressed
#7   382     1 Unsuppressed
#8   382     1 Unsuppressed
#9   382     2 Unsuppressed
```

This will select only those groups that have `'Unsuppressed'` value in all rows. Within those groups it will select all the rows with `type = 1` and the first row with `type = 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ronak Shah.  one more question if the last group id of my data looks like id =(460, 460, 460), type=(1,2,2), status=(Unsuppressed, Unsuppressed, Unsuppressed). This is met my criteria as it must be at least two times **Unsuppressed** consecutively in status 1  just before switching to status 1. So can we exclude this id from your code Ronak Shah?